# Jensen's for continuous convex combinations

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, distribution-theory, jensen-inequality

Let $d_p(u(x), v(x)) = \left( \int_0^m \left| u(x)-v(x) \right|^p dx \right)^{1/p}$ be the distance according to the $\ell_p$ norm of two functions $u,v:[0,m]\to [0,M]$. Is the following true for the distance of a continuous convex combination to some (fixed) set of functions $S$?

$$ \inf_{g\in S} d_p\left( \int_0^m w(y) f(x,y) dy, g(x) \right) \leq \int_0^m w(y) \inf_{g\in S} d_p\left( f(x,y), g(x) \right) dy $$

where $w(y) \geq 0,\ \forall y\geq 0,\ \int_0^m w(y) dy = 1$

My intuition tells me that some version of Jensen should make this true, but I'm not sure to what extent it matters that we're in infinite-dimensional spaces. I'm willing to assume that all the infimums here exist and are finite, all integrals converge, etc.

Comment: $f$ has one parameter in some places and two in others. Hard to understand.

Comment: @copper.hat, sorry, the initial one was just for understanding the definition of a distance. Changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main result won't hold in general, but a weaker result will hold. This weaker inequality is, in fact, a direct application of Jensen's inequality, and can be stated as follows:

$$\inf_{g\in S}\left\{d_p\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy, g(x)\right)\right\} \leq \inf_{g\in S}\left\{\int_0^m w(y)d_{p}(f(x,y), g(x))dy\right\}$$

## Proving the original inequality does not hold

Consider the functions given by $w(y)=\frac{1}{m}$, $f(x,y)=\sin(x(y+1))$ and $S=\{g_z(x)=\sin(x(z+1)), 0\leq z\leq m\}$.

For any *fixed* $y\in(0,m)$ we have that $$d_p(f(x,y),g_y(x))=0$$ so we can conclude that $$\inf_{g\in S}\{d_p(f(x,y),g(x))\}=0$$ and in particular $$\int_0^m w(y) \inf_{g\in S}\{d_p(f(x,y),g(x))\} dy=0$$

However, it turns out that
$$\int_0^m w(y) f(x,y) dy = \frac{-\cos(x(y+1))}{mx}\bigg|_{y=0}^{y=m}=\frac{\cos(x)-\cos((m+1)x)}{mx}$$

The map
$$z\mapsto \left(\int_0^m \left|\frac{\cos(x)-\cos((m+1)x)}{mx} \sin(x(z+1))\right|^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
is continuous so it will achieve a minimum over $[0,m]$ which is compact. Since the function $$x\mapsto \left|\frac{\cos(x)-\cos((m+1)x)}{mx} \sin(x(z+1))\right|^p$$ is continuous and for every fixed $z$ there will exist some $x$ such that it is strictly positive, none of the integrals are zero. Then the minimum is strictly positive, and we have that
$$\inf_{g\in S}\left\{d_p\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy, g(x)\right)\right\} = \\ \min_{z\in[0,m]} \left\{\left(\int_0^m \left|\frac{\cos(x)-\cos((m+1)x)}{mx} \sin(x(z+1))\right|^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \right\} > \\ 0 = \int_0^m w(y) \inf_{g\in S}\{d_p(f(x,y),g(x))\} dy$$
which disproves the inequality in the general case.

As to some intuition as to how I came up with the counterexample, it seemed that $\inf$ being over every $g\in S$ inside the integral gave way too much freedom to approximate $f$ - a luxury that each particular function $g$ wouldn't have while approximating $\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy$. This led me to choose a class of functions similar to $f$, in order to ensure the infimum always equaled zero, but complex enough so that the approximations would *always* differ by some margin. Then, I tampered around with increasingly complex functions ($x+y$ didn't work as the infimum was achieved, $\sin(xy)$ didn't work for the same reason as when $y=0$ then $\sin(xy)=0$, and then $\sin(x(y+1))$ which fixed this problem) until I found these ones which seemed to do the trick.

## Proving the weaker result

Since $w\geq 0$, $\int_0^m w(y)dy=1$, we have that $w$ is the probability density function for a probability measure $\mu_w$ in $[0,m]$. Due to the Radon Nikodym theorem, we have that $$\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy = \int_0^m f(x,y)d\mu_w(y) = \mathbb{E}_{\mu_w}[f(x,Y)]$$ for each $x\in [0,m]$.

Now, let $d_{p,g}(h)=d_p(h,g)$ and then $d_{p,g}$ is a convex function. We will have that by Jensen's inequality:
\begin{align*}
d_p\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy, g(x)\right) &= d_{p, g}\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy\right) \\
&= d_{p, g}\left(\int_0^m f(x,y)d\mu_w(y)\right) \\
&\leq \int_0^m d_{p,g}(f(x,y))d\mu_w(y) \\ 
& = \int_0^m w(y)d_{p}(f(x,y), g(x))dy 
\end{align*}
Then we can conclude that:
\begin{align*}
\inf_{h\in S}\left\{d_p\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy, h(x)\right)\right\}&\leq d_p\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy, g(x)\right) \\
&\leq \int_0^m w(y)d_{p}(f(x,y), g(x))dy
\end{align*}
for every $g\in S$, so in particular:
\begin{align*}
\inf_{g\in S}\left\{d_p\left(\int_0^m w(y)f(x,y)dy, g(x)\right)\right\}&\leq\inf_{g\in S}\left\{\int_0^m w(y)d_{p}(f(x,y), g(x))dy\right\}
\end{align*}
as we wished to prove.

Comment: In the case that both $g(x)$ and $\int_0^m w(y) f(x,y) dy$ were non-increasing in $x$, would this make the original one hold? I'm wondering if some relaxation could allow the $\inf$ to pass inside. Or is there a counterexample in the non-increasing case too?

Comment: Try $f(x,y)=-e^{x(y+1)}=g_y(x)$.

Comment: I would have loved to try to use one of the convergence theorems for the Lebesgue integral and dominated/monotone convergence seem the most likely to work in my opinion. For example, if $d_p(f(x,y),g_n(x))\to \inf_{g\in S}\{d_p(f(x,y),g(x))\}$ almost everywhere (in a monotone fashion if need be). Maybe this can be extended to uncountable $S$ if $d_p(f(x,y),g_z(x))\to \inf_{g\in S}\{d_p(f(x,y),g(x))\}$ (with additional hypothesis) as $z$ goes to a certain number, if one could index $S$ appropriately.

Comment: Do you have a particular case where you want to use your inequality? Maybe you can post a separate question or edit this one to specifically tackle this question in your concrete case (you can link to this question or use an argument of your own to mention what you learned about the problem already).